# how present Class with storyboard

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I write UI programmatically, now I want to add ui from storyboard, when I try to do it, compiler says "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

In storyboard -> ViewController -> Custom Class I set my class. Also I set ID "board1"
Why it set nil value???

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        table.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let registerViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "board1") as? RegisterViewController
        present(registerViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Which line do you get this `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on?

Comment: Can you show your storyboard? Specifically, the identity inspector of the VC.

Comment: @zaitsman this line `present (registerViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Sweeper [link] (https://imgur.com/a/PdTkgU5)

Comment: How is `storyboard` defined?

Comment: @Sweeper What do you mean ?

Comment: In the line `let registerViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "board1") as? RegisterViewController` you used a variable called `storyboard`. Can you show how it is defined?

Comment: @Sweeper Jump do definition: `@available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open var storyboard: UIStoryboard? { get }`

Comment: It seems like you are using some storyboard that is not your `Main.storyboard` file. Try replacing `storyboard` with `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`.

Comment: @Sweeper It works, thank you! may be it happens because I wrote my own navigationController in AppDelegate.swift ?

Comment: What file did you go to when you did "Go to definition"?

Comment: @Sweeper `let registerViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "board1") as? RegisterViewController` in this line in my class, I press "storyboard" -> Jump to definition

Comment: I mean which file did you jump to after you pressed "Jump to Definition"?

Comment: @Sweeper into class UIViewController

Comment: Ah! that explains it. [`storyboard`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) is the storyboard from which the VC is presented. Since your table VC is not presented by a storyboard, `storyboard` is nil.

Comment: Your optionals hides programming mistakes, just force unwrap them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using some unknown instance of `storyboard` here:

```
let registerViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "board1") as? RegisterViewController
```

According to your comments, `storyboard` doesn't seem to be declared by you. This means that it probably is not referring to your `Main.storyboard` file, and could even be nil.

You should create a new `UIStoryboard` instance that refers to your `Main.storyboard` file, like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let registerViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "board1") as? RegisterViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

```
// Perform the segue to the viewController you want. Make sure you set the identifier the same as in the storyboard

let VC1 = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier"))!
self.present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It's also possible to write an extension for this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presentView(withIdentifier: String) {
        if let newVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: withIdentifier) {
        self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like this

```
self.presentView(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")
```